# Derivation and linear spaces: decompositions in invariant spaces

Tags: linear-algebra

Let $D$ be the derivation operator on $V=\mathbb{R}[x]_{\le n}$. Suppose there exists a decomposition $V=W_1 \oplus W_2$, where $W_1$ and $W_2$ are both invariant with respect to $D$. What can I argue about $W_1$ or $W_2$. I think that one of them must be $(0)$, but I can't prove it. Can you help me, please?

My argument is the following: a decomposition as above implies that $D$ is diagonalizable. But this is not true, right?

Comment: (1) Why the decomposition mean $\;D\;$ is diagonalizable, (2) Why isn't this last true? The first one is, in general, false, and the second one is true...but why?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Assume you can find such a decomposition and write $x^n = p_1 + p_2$ with $p_i \in W_i$. Note that at least one of the $p_i$ must have degree $n$. Assume (renaming if neccesary) that $\deg(p_1) = n$ and write

$$ p_1 = a_n x^n + \dots + a_1 x^1 + a_0 $$

with $a_n \neq 0$. Then since $\deg(D^i(p_1)) = n - i$ (and in particular, $D^n(p_1) = n! \cdot a_n \neq 0$), the collection $(p_1, D(p_1), \dots, D^n(p_1))$ is linearly independent and so $W_1 = \mathbb{R}_{\leq n}[x]$.